# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, exec, runtime.exec

When I run this in my Windows command prompt it opens the default browser and loads the respective page:

```
START: http://google.com
```

I am trying to do the same thing with the Java code below but get an error message.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"START", "http://google.com"});
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "START": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at Test2.main(Test2.java:78)
```

I am running Windows Vista.

Comment: try using iexplore/firefox instead of start. I guess "start" would just be a shortcut rather than an executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that START is a command prompt builtin rather than an executable file, so you can't call it from Java.  If you want to view a webpage with the system's default browser, use [java.awt.Desktop.browse()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29).